# Need to get user consent to send UILocalNotifications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

App store approval guideline says that "Apps that send Push Notifications without first obtaining user consent will be rejected". Is that the same case for UILocalNotifications? Apps need to get user consent to send the local notifications too?

I don't really know about it. Pardon me if this is an obvious question..

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Literally yesterday an app I coded was accepted, featuring local notifications, with no dependency on prior user acceptance. It's probably a rule to prevent unexpected data consumption on the network, whereas local notifications don't use the network.